# I need to store large amounts of data in terms of time and source as dimensions. How should I design my database?

Tags: database-design, c#

My project needs to save a large amount of historical data from sensors, and the number of them is large.
Although we have eliminated part of the data by the anti-jitter and anti-duplication, but becaues of my project needs to keeping running for a long time, so it still will generates a lot of records.
I used tried SQL Server and MySQL to save these records, and divide the data into tables by sensor(source) or time (Daily, Monthly).

```
[by sensor]
his_data_Dev1
his_data_Dev2
his_data_Dev3

[by time(daily)]
his_Data_20210301
his_Data_20210302
his_Data_20210303

[by time(monthly)]
his_Data_202101
his_Data_202102
```

example data:(no device column in divide by device)

| device | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dev1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:12 | 3.53 |
| Dev1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:23 | 3.44 |
| Dev1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:26 | 3.52 |
| Dev1 | 2021-03-01 00:00:33 | 3.53 |

But they are not easy to query and still have performance bottlenecks.
Currently looking for a better solution, which can better save large amounts of data (records for several years), and faster query speed (especially aggregate computing, we need to aggregate and calculate the historical values of a each device in units of years.).

The solution accepts to change to another database - but at least it should support .NET Core access.

Comment: We are considering saving historical data as a separate database for each year, and saving all aggregate calculation results. I'm not sure if this is a good idea (maybe it is?).

Comment: We have found some query statements that can be optimized and solved some performance problems. But we still hope to get a better solution.

Comment: All modern relational database management systems are going to perform more or less the same, so need to consider switching between database system for performance reasons alone. How many rows is currently in the table, about how many rows are there per device for a given year, and about how many new rows is the table growing by over a given timeframe (e.g. per day)? Proper indexing and architecture will be your best bet here, and SQL Server has some cool features to help with this stuff. For reference, I've worked with tables in the 10s of billions of records, and their performance was fine.